# Extracting specific numerical values

Tags: python

I have data of the following form:

```
<A>  <pred>       "7630000.0"^^<m^2> .
<R>     <pred>       "2150000.0e11"^^xsd:integer .
<G>      <pred>       "5.85E7"^^</km^2> .
<T>   <pred>       "4810000.0"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger> .
<Y>   "this 18"       "1.863E8"^^<s> .
<D>      <pred>       "2023428.2112e09"^^<> .
<GS>   <wd>     "760mm"^^<en> .
<Vi>       <hasIn>  "13.89"^^<%> .
```

Now I want to extract all numerical values within the last quotes and store them into a file. Note, that here I want to leave all non-numerical values e.g. "760mm". For example for the above example, I want to extract the following numerical values:

```
7630000.0, 2150000.0e11, 5.85E7, 4810000.0, 1.863E8, 2023428.2112e09, 13.89,
```

I tried doing the same by splitting on " but by doing so I end up getting 18 also which I do not want. Is there some way in python or using linux commands by which I may achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect the format will change? Do you expect any valid characters other than numerals, decimal points, and 'e'/'E'?
I'd do what you did, store the items in a list, and exclude anything not a number.

```
for char in possible_number:
    if char not in '0123456789.eE':
        # exclude item...
```

Comment: Yes the format may change. I only expect numerical values: integers, floats, etc